# increase number of connections per file download on XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I ran a server with Xampp. When i put a file on htdocs folder and try to download it on a client with a download manager, only 2 simultaneous connections are allowed per file. How can I increase this number?

Comment: What are you using to download?

Comment: IDM. I have set max connection per file in IDM to 16. I can download with 16 connections from some other hosts, but not my own!

Comment: I know it should be somewhere in httpd-mpm.conf. There are many options there, so I can not find what I want among them!